# ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am building a simple algorithm to find common divisors between two given numbers:

```
i = int(input("digite o 1o inteiro positivo: "))
j = int(input("digite o 2o inteiro positivo: "))

#i,j = 9,6 
aux, cont = 1, 0 

if i > j: # 9 < 6 
    for n in range (i+1): # n = (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9) 
        while n <= i: # (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9) 
            if i % n == 0 and j % n == 0: # 9 % (1,3,9) e 6 % (1,3,6) 
                print(n) # print(1,3)
```

Why is my programm having this `ZeroDivisionError`?

Comment: Because n is zero.

Comment: Did you try to inspect/print any of the values in the loop to see why or possibly [Catch the error](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) and inspect the data in the except suite?  What did you find?  what possible errors have you ruled out?

Answer (score 3):

Start your [`range()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#func-range) at 1, not 0 with:

#### Code:

```
for n in range(1, i + 1):  # n = (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
```

#### Test Code:

```
i, j = 9, 6
if i > j:  # 9 < 6
    for n in range(1, i + 1):  # n = (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
        if i % n == 0 and j % n == 0:  # 9 % (1,3,9) e 6 % (1,3,6)
            print(n)  # print(1,3)
```

#### Results:

```
1
3
```

Answer (score 1):

Your loop starts with `0` so this `ZeroDivisionError` occurs.

> exception ZeroDivisionError
>   Raised when the second argument of a division or modulo operation is zero. The associated value is a string indicating the type of the operands and the operation.[[source]](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html)

You have to start your for loop from `1`

like this: `for n in range(1,i+1):`

and you don't have to do `while loop` this will go infinite.

your code will be:

```
i = int(input("digite o 1o inteiro positivo: "))
j = int(input("digite o 2o inteiro positivo: "))

# i,j = 9,6 
aux, cont = 1, 0 

if i > j: # 9 < 6
    for n in range (1,i+1): # n = (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
        #while n <= i: # (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
        if i % n == 0 and j % n == 0: # 9 % (1,3,9) e 6 % (1,3,6)
            print(n) # print(1,3)
```

or you can also write your code in `try-except` block, like this which will give the same output:

```
i = int(input("digite o 1o inteiro positivo: "))
j = int(input("digite o 2o inteiro positivo: "))

# i,j = 9,6 
aux, cont = 1, 0 

if i > j: # 9 < 6
    for n in range (i+1): # n = (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
        try:
          if i % n == 0 and j % n == 0: # 9 % (1,3,9) e 6 % (1,3,6)
              print(n) # print(1,3)
        except ZeroDivisionError:
            n+= 1
```

#### output

```
digite o 1o inteiro positivo: 9
digite o 2o inteiro positivo: 6

1
3
```

Answer (score 0):

I actually just wanted to indent the code in your question, but I ended up accidentally repairing it. So, here is a working solution:

```
i = int(input("Give the first positive integer: "))
j = int(input("Give the second positive integer: "))

r = j
if i < j:
  r = i

for n in range (2, r + 1):
  if i % n == 0 and j % n == 0:
    print(n)
```

Output:

```
Give the first positive integer: 27
Give the second positive integer: 18
3
9
```

The range starts with `2`, because `1` is a unit, and therefore not interesting as divisor (it divides everything anyway). The `0` should not be checked, because it does not divide anything, and because it caused Div-by-zero errors.

Whatever... Refreshed some python...

Answer (score 0):

Function range() can have up to 3 arguments:

range(initial limit included, final limit not included, step)

- If you use for x in range(y) with only one argument, and such case is
  equal to: for y in range(0, x, 1) # including: [0, 1, ..., x - 1]
- If you need to start your range with 1, you need to define it: for y
  in range(1, y)
- If you need to change range step, you also need to define it: for y
  in range(0, -50, -1)